# How can I iterate through multilevel json data to return a card in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm working with travelpayouts API, after fetching flight data between two airports, I'm getting a multilevel json data

```
obj = {
  BLR: {
    "0": {
      price: 170,
      airline: "6E",
      flight_number: 541,
      departure_at: "2020-07-02T19:00:00Z",
      return_at: "2020-07-16T18:15:00Z",
      expires_at: "2020-07-02T13:30:00Z"
    },
    "2": {
      price: 272,
      airline: "UK",
      flight_number: 642,
      departure_at: "2020-07-02T16:00:00Z",
      return_at: "2020-07-16T17:15:00Z",
      expires_at: "2020-07-02T10:30:00Z"
    }
  },
  MAA: {
    "2": {
      price: 286,
      airline: "AI",
      flight_number: 427,
      departure_at: "2020-07-02T20:00:00Z",
      return_at: "2020-07-11T19:15:00Z",
      expires_at: "2020-07-02T14:30:00Z"
    }
  }
};
```

Now I want to iterate through this data to make a card for each available flight and display the price, name of airline, flight number etc in the card, but I'm unable to figure out how should I go about doing it.
I tried to do it using for in loop, using

```
for(let i in obj) {
  for(data in i) {
    price = data.price;
    flightNumber = data.flight_number; //and so on
  }
}
```

but using the above code, I'm getting price, flightNumber as undefined. How should I do that?

Comment: This is tagged for react, but to be totally honest, using a for-in loop isn't that common in react. What are you doing with `price` and `flightNumber`? For the double-nested loop you have you'll just overwrite each on each iteration and the last write are the values you will be left with. My intuition is leading me to say you really want to map this flight data to *some* UI.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion,
You got my point, yes, I want to map through the flight data to make card for each flight available, I'm a fresher doing my first internship, so this is more likely a mistake or you can say lack of knowledge and experience of a newbie.
I'll be really grateful if you suggest me how can I do it in a correct way.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example rendering and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The for/in statement loops through the properties of an object not the values. You have to get the values from the object for iteration.

```
for(let key in obj) {
  for(flightId in obj[key]) {
    let flight = obj[key][flightId];
    price = flight.price;
    flightNumber = flight.flight_number; //and so on
  }
}
```

or you can use javaScript `Object.values` functions for iterating Object values.

```
Object.values(obj).forEach(airport => {
        Object.values(airport).forEach(flight=>{
            price = flight.price;
            flightNumber = flight.flight_number;
        })
    })
```

Comment:  `i` should be named `iataCode` and `data` can be named `flightId`. This makes your code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values` to grab the array of values to iterate over. Will be more handy if you are *really* trying to map this data to UI components in react.

```
Object.values(obj).forEach(airport => {
  Object.values(airport).forEach(flight => {
    let price = flight.price;
    let flightNumber = flight.flight_number;
  });
});
```

```js
const obj = {
  BLR: {
    "0": {
      price: 170,
      airline: "6E",
      flight_number: 541,
      departure_at: "2020-07-02T19:00:00Z",
      return_at: "2020-07-16T18:15:00Z",
      expires_at: "2020-07-02T13:30:00Z"
    },
    "2": {
      price: 272,
      airline: "UK",
      flight_number: 642,
      departure_at: "2020-07-02T16:00:00Z",
      return_at: "2020-07-16T17:15:00Z",
      expires_at: "2020-07-02T10:30:00Z"
    }
  },
  MAA: {
    "2": {
      price: 286,
      airline: "AI",
      flight_number: 427,
      departure_at: "2020-07-02T20:00:00Z",
      return_at: "2020-07-11T19:15:00Z",
      expires_at: "2020-07-02T14:30:00Z"
    }
  }
};

Object.values(obj).forEach(airport => {
  Object.values(airport).forEach(flight => {
    console.log('price', flight.price);
    console.log('flight#', flight.flight_number);
  });
});
```

## One Possible Solution

If you want to map this data to UI here's one of many ways to do it.

Given *some* UI component

```
const Flight = ({ flightNumber, price }) => (
  <div className="flightCard">
    <h2>Flight</h2>
    <div>
      <span>Flight Number: </span>
      <span>{flightNumber}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Price: </span>
      <span>${Number(price).toFixed(2)}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

The data can be mapped as such

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.values(data).flatMap(airport =>
        Object.values(airport).map(({ flight_number, price }) => (
          <Flight flightNumber={flight_number} price={price} />
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Map Flight Data]

### How it Works

**First** solve the smaller/simpler issue of mapping the flights from a single  airport object, i.e. `data.BLR`

```
Object.values(data.BLR).map(({ flight_number, price }) => (
  <Flight flightNumber={flight_number} price={price} />
))
```

Here in the callback we're destructuring the `flight_number` and `price` properties from each object and passing to the appropriate `Flight` component props.

This results in an array of `Flight` components, i.e. `[<Flight .../>, ...]`.

**Second** is to now map *all* the airports. A naive approach would be to also map these.

```
Object.values(data).map(airport =>
  Object.values(airport).map(({ flight_number, price }) => (
    <Flight flightNumber={flight_number} price={price} />
  ))
)
```

This would result in an array of arrays of `Flights`, i.e. `[[<Flight .../>, ...], [<Flight .../>, ...], ...]`, but this still isn't quite what can be rendered into the UI, so we can flatten this down to an array of depth 1 with [array::flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
Object.values(data).map(airport =>
  Object.values(airport).map(({ flight_number, price }) => (
    <Flight flightNumber={flight_number} price={price} />
  ))
).flat()
```

This is a common enough use-case that included in JS is a single function [array::flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

> The **`flatMap()`** method first maps each element using a mapping function,
> then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a `map()`
> followed by a `flat()` of depth 1, but `flatMap()` is often quite useful,
> as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

```
Object.values(data).flatMap(airport =>
  Object.values(airport).map(({ flight_number, price }) => (
    <Flight flightNumber={flight_number} price={price} />
  ))
)
```

This will do the same mapping as above and flatten it all down to a flat array of `Flight` components, `[<Flight .../>, <Flight .../>, <Flight .../>, ...]`